# Working out Viewport Height for slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, viewport

The URL: http://beautyatthebay.gs-dev.net.

I am trying to archive that when you go to the homepage of the above website, the header area is displayed which is a fixed height of 125px and 100% width.

I now need to work out the viewport height, minus the header (125px), so that I can set the height on the element of the LayerSlider.

How can I do this?

Thanks,
Josh

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).height() - 125; // Will give you height of window minus your 125 px menu/header
```